# React Router 6 useParams() is not returning the most recent path param

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am practicing recursive routing in react router 6 after following this [guide](https://ui.dev/react-router-recursive-paths) and the useParams function is giving me some weird behavior. It is being called multiple times for each time I link to a new component - often it's undefined, often it is not returning the most recent path param. for example if my path/is/this, it is returning "is."

The getItems() function just returns some json that represents a file tree structure that I'm parsing and I need a reliable return from useParams.

Here is my app.js:

```
export function Folder() {
  const { dirName } = useParams();
  const {name, items} = getItems(dirName);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
        <ul>
          {items.filter((dir) => dir.type ==="dir").map(({ name, type }) => (
            <li key={name}>
              <Link to={name}>{name}, {type}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={`:dirName/*`} element={<Folder />} />
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};


function App() {
    

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/first" />} />
        <Route path="/:dirName/*" element={<Folder />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That guide is for rendering a nested route, nothing recursive, so there's only ever a single `id` path param. In your code you are effectively declaring a bunch of route path params all named `dirName`, so I'm not surprised the `useParams` hook is only returning one of them. Each route path param should identify a unique path segment it represents.

Comment: What I want to be able to do is infinitely link to the same Folder component as I step into each nested folder (as defined by the JSON object) just like google drive, basically. Forgive me, I'm new to react and react-router, but is this not a good way to go about this? I'm also struggling to see how my implementation differs from the one in the guide other than the dirName/id variable name difference.

Comment: The implementation isn't different, per se, with regards to matching and rendering a single route and routed component, it's more the overall use case. In that guide the `Person` component isn't recursively rendering itself. I did have an idea/thought about how to address/handle the "duplicate" `dirName` params though. Would it be possible to create a *running* codesandbox demo of the code you have so far that we could inspect and debug with?

Comment: Sure [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-banach-3f7u99?file=/src/App.js) is the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of using this `getItems` utility to compute the `directory` object entry based on a `dirName` route param, change the way you recursively render the `Folder` component to pass in the current entry as a prop.

Example:

```
function Folder({ data }) {
  const { dirName } = useParams();
  console.log({ dirName });
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1> // <-- same as dirName
      <ul>
        {data.items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.name}>
            {item.type === "file" && (
              <>
                {item.name}, {item.size}
              </>
            )}
            {item.type === "dir" && (
              <>
                <Link to={item.name}>
                  {item.name}, {item.type}
                </Link>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path=":dirName/*" element={<Folder data={item} />} />
                </Routes>
              </>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Seed the initial route.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/top" />} />
  <Route path="/:dirName/*" element={<Folder data={directory[0]} />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-6-useparams-is-not-returning-the-most-recent-path-param]

[image]

Comment: This is a huge help, thanks! One thing I noticed, though. I added another directory next to "bin" and when I click either link, it always opens both of them up. Also, If I only wanted to render the most recent directory, how can I achieve this? for example, when entering the "bin" directory, I no longer want to see the "top" directory.